# Jquery hide() text is printed/Selected

Tags: jquery, css

i have a

```
<div>.......</div>
<div id="some_id"></div>
```

and in my script i have done

```
$('#my_button').click(function(){
$('#some_id').toggle();
})
```

so initially the text withing the div is hidden using style=display:none , but when i take a print out , the hidden text is also printed ! what i want is that only when text in  is visible only then it show be displayed in the print out , if hidden it should not come in the print out

To recreate , create two div tags and make one of them style= display:none , now open the webpage in IE and do a select All , when u paste in a MS word or excel you will see even hidden text is selected

i think i need to use @media of css but i cant figure it out

Comment: if text in <div id="some_id"> is shown then only it should be printed while taking print out , if text in the div is hidden then dont print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stylesheet use this:

```
@media print {
.noPrint {
    display:none;
}
}
```

Then add `class='noprint'` (or add the noprint class to an exsiting class statement) in your HTML that you don't want to appear at the time of printing. like this

```
$('#my_button').click(function(){
     $('#some_id').toggle();
     if($('#some_id').is(":visible"))
     {
        $('#some_id').removeClass('noprint');
     }
     else
     {
        $('#some_id').addClass('noprint');
     }
})
```

Comment: if text is shown , then i want to print it , if its hidden i dont want to print , is your code for the same ?

Comment: when you are doing toggle when your div will be hidden set it's class using addClass('noprint') and when div will be shown use removeClass('noprint')

Comment: Instead of add/removeClass you can use toggleClass("noprint")

Comment: @rahul , give me a moment will try and get back

Comment: @rahul, nop doesnt work , see you can recreate my problem , create 2 divs and make one of them style=display: none , now open the web page in IE and do a select all and paste in word , you will notice that even hiddden text is there

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#some_id').hide();
    if($('#some_id').text())      
        $('#some_id').toggle();
});
```

and need to remove your "display:none;" prop as well.Hope it works for you.if it,then accept my ans